# Powershell Query to show all accounts in an AD group or in an OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been asked to export the details of all service accounts in our AD domain. Seems straight forward but I have found over the years there has not be a consistent way service accounts have been controlled. We have a Service Accounts OU as well as a Service Account AD security group. Some accounts are in the OU but not the group, some in the group but another random OU, some are in both.

I can query each one individually:

Group

```
Get-ADGroupMember GROUP.ServiceAccounts
```

OU

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Service Accounts,OU=Accounts,DC=Domain,DC=com" -filter *
```

How can I combine both into one powershell query?

Comment: Combining into one query will likely result in a more inefficient query. You will probably need to query all users and then filter with `Where-Object`. I think combining your outputs into an object array will add flexibility and maintain your current lookup speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine these into one query, which will likely be more inefficient than what you are already doing, you can do the following:

```
$searchBase = '*OU=Service Accounts,OU=Accounts,DC=Domain,DC=com'
$groupDN = 'CN=Group Name,OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=com'
Get-Aduser -Filter * |
    Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -like $searchBase -or $_.MemberOf -contains $groupDN}
```

You will need to update `$groupDN` with the actual distinguished name of your group. If you could find a more efficient way to `-Filter` on `DistinguishedName`, you could make this faster with the `-Filter` parameter.

---

**Alternative Solution:**

A more efficient way would be to combine your results into an object array.

```
$array1 = Get-ADGroupMember $Group
$array2 = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Service Accounts,OU=Accounts,DC=Domain,DC=com" -filter *
$array1,$array2
```